# Making wide char file

Tags: c, windows, unicode

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* oFile;
    oFile = _wfopen(L"foo.txt",L"w");
    //*
    fwprintf(oFile,L"%s", L"ęłó☺☻♥♦•ń");
    fclose(oFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this program creates an ASCII file instead of UTF-16, though all functions are wide?!

foo.txt   Content:

> za[question mark]ó[two question marks...] g[...four...] ja[another two...] [five*?] [and the last one]

This is inconvertible.

```
fwprintf(oFile,L"%c%c%s",0xFE,0xFF,L"zażółć gęśłą jaźń ☺☻♥♦• ć");
```

Now, it shows Chinese signs, regardless of little or big endian byte order mark is set.

Comment: How are you checking that it's not creating a UTF-16 file?  Are you opening it in Notepad or in, say, a hex editor?  Notepad probably expects a UTF-16 BOM.  In general, writing UTF-16 files is usually a bad idea; it's better to serialize to UTF-8 instead.

Comment: "In general, writing UTF-16 files is usually a bad idea" @jamesdlin -I know, but it's special situation, a utf-16 file must be created. Please read the postscriptum.

Comment: @kutacz - This may be a compile-time error; consider using [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/) escape [sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals). For example, the BOM can be expressed as `L"\uFEFF"`.

Comment: @McDowell you meant    fwprintf(oFile,L"\uFEFF%s",L"zażółć gęśłą jaźń ☺☻♥♦• ć"); ? It creates an empty file.

Comment: Since you are using a C++ header (`<cstdio>`), this cannot be a C question.  Or, if it is meant to be a C question, update the code to use the C header (`<stdio.h>`) instead.  The name `_wfopen()` is not standard in either C or C++.  You should identify the compiler and platform you are working with/on (probably MSVC on Windows, but all the world is not a PC, and which version of MSVC?).

Comment: The default encoding is what Windows refers to as "ANSI" but is really the default locale's encoding, which is code page 1252 on US Windows.  Explicitly writing a byte order mark just confuses the Windows editors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using MSVC, to quote the documentation for [_wfopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) (bold mine):

> The fopen function opens the file that is specified by filename.
>   _wfopen is a wide-character version of fopen; the arguments to _wfopen are wide-character strings. Otherwise, _wfopen and fopen behave
>   identically. **Just using _wfopen has no effect on the coded character
>   set that is used in the file stream.**

Reading further in the documentation:

> fopen supports Unicode file streams. To open a Unicode file, pass a
>   ccs flag that specifies the desired encoding to fopen, as follows.
>
> fopen(&fp, "newfile.txt", "rw, ccs= encoding ");
>
> Allowed values of encoding are UNICODE, UTF-8, and UTF-16LE.

The following code writes a UTF-8-encoded file.  I saved this source file in UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, and UTF-8 and MSVC was able to compile and run correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* oFile;
    oFile = fopen("foo.txt","w, ccs=UTF-8");
    fwprintf(oFile,L"%s", L"ęłó☺☻♥♦•ń");
    fclose(oFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that displaying this output on the Windows command line requires switching to the UTF-8 code page:

```
C:\x>chcp
Active code page: 1252

C:\x>x

C:\x>type foo.txt
ï»¿Ä™Å‚Ã³â˜ºâ˜»â™¥â™¦â€¢Å„
C:\Users\metolone\Desktop\x>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\x>type foo.txt
ęłó☺☻♥♦•ń
```

Answer (score 2):

Choice of character width (char or wchar_t) in a C or C++ program has absolutely nothing to do with file encodings.

If you need, say, a UTF16LE-encoded file, you need to use a locale that specifies UTF16LE, either as your global locale, or imbued in a C++ stream. Alternatively, you may convert your characters to a  UTF16LE-encoded sequence of bytes yourself (with `iconv` or whatever its analogue on Windows) and use byte-oriented output to send it to the file.

NB1: a wide-character string requires a `"%ls"` format.

NB2: Non-ASCII characters in string literals are non-portable.

NB3: Your tag says "c", `<cstdio>` is C++, but the program is not a valid C++ program. Which language are you using? Make up your mind ;)