# UTF-8 to wide char conversion

Tags: c++, c, windows, unicode

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE* resFile;
    char multiByteStr[256];
    ifstream oFile;
    FILE* exampleFile;
    TCHAR buffer[256];      
    system("chcp 65001");

    resFile = _wfopen(L"foo",L"w, ccs=UTF-8");             
    fwprintf(resFile,L"%s",L"C:\\exsistingFolder\\zażółć gęśłą jaźń ☺☻♥♦• ć.txt");    
    fclose(resFile);   

    oFile.open(L"foo");    
    oFile.getline(multiByteStr,256,'\n');       
    oFile.close();    

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,multiByteStr,256,buffer,256);    
    wprintf(L"%s",buffer);

    exampleFile = _wfopen(buffer,L"w, ccs=UTF-16LE");       
    fwprintf(exampleFile,L"%s",buffer);     
    fclose(exampleFile);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, program should create file "foo" `resFile` that contains a full path of the file to be created, and this new file `exampleFile` should  contain a path to itself. Although during debugging in Visual studio 2010 autos yields that buffer has the correct string, exampleFile isn't created. Why?
And another thing: why `wprintf` doesn't output extended characters, though I've switched console's font to Lucida Console - that one which can deal with uncode characters.

Ps. exampleFile points to `NULL`, even after `_wfopen`, and the last character of buffer is `'/0'`.

Comment: Is `buffer` NULL terminated? Did you check the return values of the calls after `oFile.close`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making wide char file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769023/making-wide-char-file)

Comment: To print Unicode to the console, you need `_setmode` in addition to `wprintf` (but no `chcp`) – see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx.

Comment: @Hans Passant - this is different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very trivial- _wfopen creates a file encoded in UTF-8 **with BOM**, and    MultiByteToWideChar function doesn't remove the BOM, so we need to manually get rid of this.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing any error handling. Most importantly, when calling `MultiByteToWideChar()`, you are telling it to convert the entire `multiByteStr` buffer, but most of the buffer contains garbage because you did not zero it beforehand. You have to use the actual number of characters in the buffer, not the buffer's max size. `MultiByteToWideChar()` is likely returning an error that you are ignoring.  There are several other failure spots in the code as well.  You need to always check for errors, especially when interacting with the OS.

Try this:

```
#define UNICODE

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void pause()
{
    wcin.ignore();
    wcin.get();
}

int main()
{
    FILE* resFile;
    char multiByteStr[256] = {0};
    ifstream oFile;
    FILE* exampleFile;
    WCHAR buffer[256] = {0};

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    resFile = _wfopen(L"foo",L"w, ccs=UTF-8");
    if (!resFile) {
        wprintf(L"Unable to create foo");
        goto done;
    }

    fwprintf(resFile,L"%s",L"C:\\exsistingFolder\\zażółć gęśłą jaźń ☺☻♥♦• ć.txt");
    fclose(resFile);

    if (!oFile.open(L"foo")) {
        wprintf(L"Unable to open foo");
        goto done;
    }

    oFile.getline(multiByteStr,255,'\n');
    oFile.close();

    if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,multiByteStr,-1,buffer,256) == 0) {
        wprintf(L"Unable to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16. Error: %u", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    exampleFile = _wfopen(buffer,L"w, ccs=UTF-16LE"); 
    if (!exampleFile) {
        wprintf(L"Unable to create file: %s", buffer);
        goto done;
    }

    fwprintf(exampleFile,L"%s",buffer); 
    fclose(exampleFile);

    wprintf(L"created file: %s", buffer);

done:
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error-handling had been removed from my code on the purpose of simplicity. You helped me a little with MultiByteToWideChar function, but it didn't resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why mix and match your I/O libraries?  Here's a pure (Windows) C solution, minus error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* pFile;
    wchar_t buffer[256];

    _wfopen_s(&pFile,L"foo",L"w, ccs=UTF-8");
    fputws(L"C:/existingFolder/zażółć gęśłą jaźń ☺☻♥♦• ć.txt",pFile);
    fclose(pFile);

    _wfopen_s(&pFile,L"foo",L"r, ccs=UTF-8");
    fgetws(buffer,_countof(buffer),pFile);
    fclose(pFile);

    _wfopen_s(&pFile,buffer,L"w, ccs=UTF-16LE");
    fputws(buffer,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to run this? It throws run-time "debug assertion failed" message box , like my program.

Comment: It runs fine, as long as `C:/existingFolder` exists.  Add error checking to your version.  If the file doesn't open it will crash since the file handle will be NULL.  It is also important that you save the source file in an appropriate format.  I used UTF-16LE (with BOM).

Comment: My mistake, thanks about this , it's useful, it works, but it's still not an answer to my question.