# How to check range of unicode value of character in c++

Tags: c++, unicode

I am new to C++ and come from non-CS background. Hence kindly excuse me if this question is silly or has been answered before.

I have a string in c++, language is Telugu.

```
std::string str = "ఉంది"; // (it means exists; pronounced as Vundi)
std::string substring = str.substr(0,3);
```

The above substring would be "ఉ" (pronounced as Vu) and its unicode hex value is 0C09.

How can i get the value 0C09 from substring?
The purpose is to check if the substring is in the valid range for Telugu (0C00–0C7F).

I have seen other questions they apply to obj-c , java, php, c# etc. I am looking specifically for c++ using std::string.

As per the comment I have read the article at [joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Let me update my question with more information.
I am using Fedora 19 x86_64 and encoding is UTF-8. The console is able to display the text properly.

As per the article, if I understand correctly ASCII is single byte character and unicode is multibyte character. The above code sample reflects that, here it is 3 bytes in length for each unicode character. Other than talking about UTF-8/ text encoding  and multibyte characters, this article offers no practical help in detecting the language of unicode string.

May be I should rephrase my question:

How can I detect a language for unicode string in C++?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn about text encodings. This is a decent article on the topic: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html Understanding this article will make it *so* much easier to handle the problem you are facing. I recommend it :)

Comment: Thanks for the information and prompt reply. I would go through the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using string the result that i get is

```
std::string str = "ఉంది"; // (it means exists; pronounced as Vundi)
unsigned short i =str[0];
printf("%x %d",i,i);
```

The output is **"ffeo 65504"**

But when i use wstring i.e

```
std::wstring str = L"ఉంది"; // (it means exists; pronounced as Vundi)
unsigned short i =str[0];
printf("%x %d",i,i);
```

The output is **"c09 3081"** which i suppose is the right output.
I am not sure but is that what you want.Let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) or you would have to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16/32 by hand by looking at consecutive chars in the string. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for an explanation for UTF-8 multi byte chars.

ICU also includes unicode character properties, which may be helpful e.g. for detecting scripts.

`std::string` does not have any built-in support for UTF-8 to UTF-16/32 conversion, so also `substr` can not return a unicode character.

Comment: I agree with you. I was not very keen on using external libraries, sorry should have mentioned this. And do not need any of those special properties and internationalization beyond hex value of character.

Comment: As @Neet mentioned, ICU also has "exemplar chars" ( which chars are actually used by the Telugu language ), `UnicodeSet` (for performing the chars-in-range operation) as well as character props.  These give you a lot of tools for "detecting what languages a string might be", short of full blown linguistic analysis.  ICU was written so that these operations would be available in a consistent cross platform way. One might say "not an external library!" or "it's too big!" but, it takes work to get this right…

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from your encoding (utf8 probably)(char *) to wide char (wchar_t).

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774653/utf-8-to-wide-char-conversion) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl) for more information about this conversion.